# How does an iOS app keep a FBSession from expiring?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, token

I have read that FBSession automatically renews/refreshes it's token, but looking through the sdk the only time it seems to actually extend the life of the token is when a session open request returns a new token expiration.

Will the session/token get renewed as a result of other actions?

EDIT:
In the 'Facebook' class there is an 'extendAccessToken' method with the following comment:

/**
 * Attempt to extend the access token.
 *
 * Access tokens typically expire within 30-60 days. When the user uses the
 * app, the app should periodically try to obtain a new access token. Once an
 * access token has expired, the app can no longer renew it. The app then has
 * to ask the user to re-authorize it to obtain a new access token.
 *
 * To ensure your app always has a fresh access token for active users, it's
 * recommended that you call extendAccessTokenIfNeeded in your application's
 * applicationDidBecomeActive: UIApplicationDelegate method.
 */

But this method seems to be completely separate from the FBSession.

Answer (score 0):

By using the FBSession with a token, that token will be extended automatically with the newest SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBSession.m#L236-L260

Comment: The Facebook documentation at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/iossdk/session/  Mentions that the FBSession will automatically be refreshed / renewed as well.  Quickly browsing the code doesn't give a clear picture of when, how, or what actions cause the refresh to occur.